# Sequelize select statement for this example with express get method

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

I have these 2 words:
[The words in mysql db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13jAy.png)

And I have this category:
[The category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxG4d.png)

As we can see in the word-table, the words have also a categoryId attribute.

I've made an junctiontable in case I need it but it's currently empty, it looks like that:
[junction table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5ZcT.png)

I want to display a list in my ui that is a admin-panel that would look like this for example:

| Words | Category |
| --- | --- |
| God | Religion |
| Ford Mustang | Cars |

**Every word has exactly one category.**

To do that I want to use axios to fetch a get request of my node.js server.

What would look the get method with the corresponding sequelize query to get the data and maybe also the method in the react ui?

I'm trying to figure it out for about two days now and I can't get out of this shithole...

**What is the project***:**

Full stack web app that simulates the game "wheel of fortune". Contains a auth-system where admins can also make CRUD options for words, questions and create categories that belong to a word or question. Classic users can only play the game.

Technologies:

- React -> Frontend
- Node.js Backend -> Express.js and Sequelize
- Database: MySQL with mysql workbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming model name for Words table is Word and Category for category table the code to query all the data would be such:

```
const words = await Word.findAll({
            where: {
                // here you can do filtering if needed
            },
            include: [
                
                {
                    model: Category,
                    attributes: [
                        'category',
                        
                    ],
                    as: 'categories',
                    
                },
            ],
        });
```

This will return list of words and associated categories. Then you would just create api endpoint and return queried data and display on frontend.

Comment: The result looks like that (1 example): [
 {
  "id": 1,
  "word": "programing",
  "createdAt": "2023-02-12T17:44:24.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2023-02-12T17:44:24.000Z",
  "CategoryId": 1,
  "Category": {
   "category": "IT"
  }
 }, It worked for me, thank you! But how can I only take the "category" and the "word" -> programing and the category -> IT

Comment: @MaksimMomcilovic Yes, you could filter out it with adding  ```attributes: ['word'] ``` to first object(next to where statement). Or you could just loop over the returned values from sequalize and take out properties you need.

Comment: That's all I needed, thanks a lot!